# Python 3- matrix input

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, sum, row

The program i wrote a program so that main calls the following functions:

getMatrix – creates and returns a 3 x 3 matrix

printMatrix – prints the matrix row by row

sumRow – returns the sum of the elements of a single row of the matrix (pass in the matrix and the row index)

The problem i am facing is that it is asking for the input twice, instead of once.

```
def getMatrix():
   matrix = []
   numberOfRows = eval(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
   numberOfColumns = eval(input("Enter number of columns: "))
   for row in range(numberOfRows):
      matrix.append([])
      for column in range(numberOfColumns):
         value = eval(input("Enter an element and press enter: "))
         matrix[row].append(value)
   return matrix

# Print 2 dimensional list
def printMatrix(matrix):
   matrix = getMatrix()
   for row in range(len(matrix)):
      for column in range(len(matrix[row])):
         print(matrix[row][column], end = " ")
      print()

# Add each element in row to total 
def sumRow(matrix):
   for row in range(len(matrix[0])):
      total = 0
      for column in range(len(matrix)):
         total += matrix[row][column]
      print("Sum for matrix", row, "is", total)

def main():
   matrix = getMatrix()
   printMatrix(matrix)
   total = sumRow(matrix)
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main`:

```
matrix = getMatrix()
printMatrix(matrix)
```

In `printMatrix`:

```
matrix = getMatrix()
```

Which immediately masks the `matrix` argument you passed in, by the way.

In `getMatrix`:

```
matrix = []
numberOfRows = eval(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
numberOfColumns = eval(input("Enter number of columns: "))
```

You should be using `int()`, by the way, not `eval()`.

So there are two calls to `getMatrix()`, which means two requests for input. Remove `matrix = getMatrix()` from `printMatrix`. That's not what that function is supposed to be doing, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can print any m x n  matrix:

```
row = int(input("Enter number of rows you want: "))
col = int(input("Enter number of columns you want: "))

mat = []

for m in range(row):
  a = []
  for n in range(col):
     a.append(0)

  mat.append(a)

for i in range(len(mat)):
  for j in range(len(mat[0])):
    mat[i][j] = int(input("Input element: "))

print("Your Matrix is: ", mat)
```